# Why .setUTCHours returns different results?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have the following function which should read time in UTC and return in local time, and sometimes it adds 2 hours(correctly) and sometimes 4 hours. Why is that? What can be the reason?

```
value = time in UTC

toLocalDate(value) {
  let string = new Date(value);
  let date = new Date();

  date.setUTCFullYear(string.getFullYear(), string.getMonth(), string.getDate());
  date.setUTCHours(string.getHours(), string.getMinutes(), string.getSeconds(), 0);

  return date;
}
```

Example data:

```
Value: 2017-08-23T06:00:00
Expected output: Wed Aug 23 2017 08:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Daylight Time)
Output: Wed Aug 23 2017 10:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Daylight Time)
```

On some devices(like my phone or computer) it returns the expected output.
On my friend's device(mobile) it returns the second output.

Comment: Can we get an idea of the value? Give us some to test... Value A => result = X => expected = Y

Comment: i have added test data

Comment: I'm getting the expected output, not your output...

Comment: so do I, but on some devices it returns the second output and I dont know why

Comment: That shouldn't be happening... Anyways, it'd be better to store the timezone in the value so you don't have to convert it back... Easiest way would be to add Z at the end, like "2017-08-23T06:00:00Z" that will mean UTC time, and the browser will handle accordingly.